# I have problem with right construction of "if" instruction

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with construction of my function. It is supposed to detect if what user put in boxes is integer or not, and print right commentary. Problem occurs in second level of function, where instruction "if" should check again if figure1 is a number (it does not print anything), but the "else if" is read perfectly, so is "else". What is wrong with my function? Please help.

```js
function show() {
  //Variable contains the value of field1 from input html which has been read thanks to onclick
  var figure1 = document.getElementById("field1").value; 
  //Variable contains the value of field2 from input html which has been read thanks to onclick
  var figure2 = document.getElementById("field2").value; 

  //empty until the instruction write in something
  let sign = "";

  //STEP 1
  //loop working until the value of i reach the value of figure2
  for (i = figure1; i <= figure2; i++) 
  {
    if (Number(figure1) && Number(figure2)) {
      //if both figure1 and figure2 are numbers, print the sign as follows - what sign contains from previous iteration + i + ", "
      sign = sign + i + ", "; 
      
    } else {
    
      if (Number(figure1)) {
        //If statements from "if" level above haven't been fulfilled, print "Please, type integer in right-hand box";
        sign = "Proszę wpisać liczbę w prawym polu"; 
        
      } else if (Number(figure2)) {
        //If statements from "if" level above haven't been fulfilled, print "Please, type integer in left-hand box";
        sign = "Proszę wpisać liczbę w lewym polu"; 
        
      } else {
        sign = "Proszę wpisać wartości liczbowe w obu polach";
        // If statements from "if"
        // level above haven 't been fulfilled, print "Please, type integer in both boxes";
      }
    }
  }
  //podmienia wartość diva o id result na wartość zmiennej sign.
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sign; 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="field1">
  <!--W tym polu umieszczamy liczbę z przedziału-->
  <input type="text" id="field2">
  <!--W tym polu umieszczamy liczbę z przedziału-->
  <input type="submit" value="pokaż" onclick="show()">
  <!--Po kliknięciu zostaje wywołana funkcja "show()"-->
  <div id="result"></div>
  <!--wnętrze diva podmienimy przy użyciu funkcji "show()"-->
</body>
```

Comment: Using a for loop based on the values doesn't really make sense. What is your thinking in using such a loop?

Comment: Please include sample input, expected output and actual output along with any error messages. Note that `if (Number(figure1))` will resolve to false if the value of *figure1* is "0" or "" (empty string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot comment (not enough reputation) so I will write my comment in the form of an answer.

There are 3 problems with this line of your code:

```
for (i = figure1; i <= figure2; i++)
```

1. You say that the point of the function is to make sure that both figure1 and figure2 are numbers, but by putting them inside a loop like that you already assume that they are.
   Think about it - if the values are not numbers, how can you increment them and compare them withing a for loop?
2. You assume that figure1 is always smaller than figure2. I there a basis for this assumption? If its false than the loop will not execute even once.
3. Forthermore, I don't get why the loop is needed. If you want to check whether the inputs are integer or not, than what do you need to loop and change their values? Checking once should be enough.

Fix these issues and check if your problem persists.

Comment: I rethought the code and now it works perfectly. Anyway - much thanks for advices :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function show()
        {
            var figure1 = document.getElementById("field1").value; //Zmienna przechowuje wartość pola field1, które zostaje zczytane po wywołaniu funkcji przy użyciu zdarzenia "onclick"
            var figure2 = document.getElementById("field2").value; //Zmienna przechowuje wartość pola field2, które zostaje zczytane po wywołaniu funkcji przy użyciu zdarzenia "onclick"

            let sign = ""; //zmienna przechowuje pusty ciąg znaków, do momentu nadpisania jej zawartości przez instrukcje funkcji

            if (Number(figure1) && Number(figure2))
            {
                for (i=figure1; i<=figure2; i++) //pętla wykonująca się dopóki wartość figure1 jest mniejsza lub równa figure2
                {
                        sign = sign + i + ", "; //jeżeli obie wartości pobrane z pól field1 i field2 są liczbami, to wykonuj instrukcję pętli for, tj. inkrementuj wartość i od wartości field1 do wartości field2
                }

                for (i=figure1; i>=figure2; i--)
                {
                    sign = sign + i + ", "
                }
            }
            else if (Number(figure1))
            {
                sign = "Proszę wpisać wartość liczbową w polu prawym";
            }
            else if (Number(figure2))
            {
                sign = "Proszę wpisać wartość liczbową w polu lewym";
            }
            else
            {
                sign = "Proszę wpisać wartości liczbowe w polach prawym i lewym";
            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sign; //podmienia wartość diva o id result na wartość zmiennej sign.
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="field1"> <!--W tym polu umieszczamy liczbę z przedziału-->
    <input type="text" id="field2"> <!--W tym polu umieszczamy liczbę z przedziału-->
    <input type="submit" value="pokaż" onclick="show()"> <!--Po kliknięciu zostaje wywołana funkcja "show()"-->

    <div id="result"></div> <!--wnętrze diva podmienimy przy użyciu funkcji "show()"-->

</body>
</html>
```